# Using EJBs with regular java classes. Trying to instantiate a stateless EJB

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have a large web project in Java EE 6 so far everything is working great.

Now I'm adding a new class that takes twitter information and returns a string. So far the strings have been extracted from the JSON file from twitter and are ready to be persisted in my database. My problem is I'm not sure how to pass information from the EJB that normally handles all of my database calls. I'm using JPA and have a DAO class that managers all database access. I already have a method there for `updateDatabase(String)`. I'd like to be able to call `updateDatabase(String)` from the class that has the strings to add but I don't know if it's good form to instantiate a stateless bean like that. Normally you inject beans and then call just their class name to access their methods. I could also maybe try and reference the twitter string generating class from inside of the EJB but then I'd have to instantiate it there and mess with main() method calls for execution. I'm not really sure how to do this.  Right now my Twitter consuming class is just a POJO with a main method. For some reason some of the library methods did not work outside of main in face IOUtils() API directly says "Instances should NOT be constructed in standard programming".

So on a higher level bottom line, I'm just asking how POJO's are normally "mixed" into a Java EE project where most of your classes are EJBs and servlets.

Edit: the above seems confusing to me after rereading so I'll try to simplify it. basically I have a class with a main method. I'd like to call my EJB class that handles database access and call it's `updateDatabase(String)` method and just pass in the string. How should I do this?

Edit: So it looks like a JNDI lookup and subsequence reference is the preferred way to do this rather than instantiating the EJB directly?

Edit: these classes are all in the same web project. In the same package. I could inject one or convert the POJO to an EJB. However the POJO does have a main method and some of the library files do not like to be instantiated so running it in main seems like the best option.

My main code:

```
public class Driver {

    @EJB
    static RSSbean rssbean;   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxya..com");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        /////////////auth code///////////////auth code/////////////////
        String username = System.getProperty("proxy.authentication.username");
        String password = System.getProperty("proxy.authentication.password");
        if (username == null) {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("", ""));
        }
        ///////////////end auth code/////////////////////////////////end

        URL twitterSource = new URL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=google");
        ByteArrayOutputStream urlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        IOUtils.copy(twitterSource.openStream(), urlOutputStream);
        String urlContents = urlOutputStream.toString();
        JSONObject thisobject = new JSONObject(urlContents);
        JSONArray names = thisobject.names();
        JSONArray asArray = thisobject.toJSONArray(names);
        JSONArray resultsArray = thisobject.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject(urlContents.substring(urlContents.indexOf('s')));                
        JSONObject jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);

        String twitterText = jsonObject.getString("text");          
        rssbean.updateDatabase("twitterText"); 
    }
}
```

I'm also getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` somewhere around `rssbean.updateDatabase("twitterText");`

Comment: You shold not create an instance of EJB. Ever. That is something the the conainer handles. What you could do on the other hand, is to put an PostConstruct annotation on a method and do something there (instead of constructor), but that's not related to your problem

Comment: Ok, the reason why that EJB is null is probably because the Driver class is not container managed class. This should work only if the Driver class is application entry point class (that's the only way you can inject EJB on static field). However, you said that this is a web application. So where from do you call Driver.main()? Anyway, if you really need to have that code in a static method (assuming it's not the entrypoint), I see either JNDI lookup or refactoring your code around factory pattern to inject the instance or something along those lines.

Comment: I was just using the main method as a way to test the operations. I don't necessarily need it for the web application.  Although I'm not sure what mechanism I would use to trigger the operations of getting data from the URL and then adding to the database. I would need some kind of automatic execution for that.

Comment: Ah, but that is very important information, that's why I asked how you execute this. I'm not really sure, what your use case is, but if you need automatic execution for your logic, use the \@Schedule annotation. Or MDB. Or something else altogether. But for this to work, you cannot just run this with Java SE and throw \@EJB at it. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862445/can-an-ejb-be-called-from-a-desktop-application

Comment: Ok so basically you cannot call an EJB from a standard POJO non container managed class unless you use JNDI lookup? Even if you don't get a compile error you'll get a null point exception.  So my only other choice is to convert this to a normal EJB using a @schedule annotation and inject the database management EJB into this EJB where I can then make the appropriate calls?

Comment: you have to use JNDI for that, correct. You'll get null pointer, correct. schedule is for ejb timer service, that's for automatic execution you asked about. If you are going to execute your Twitter class from say a JSF controller (which is therefore going to be a managed object, so called backing bean), then you can convert it to EJB, inject the DAO EJB etc. and you're done. Otherwise, use JNDI.

Comment: great thank you. I'll mark your answer as correct. TDIL that when adding business logic to interract with existing EJBs you have two choices of either JNDI or converting a main class to an EJB that uses EJB timer service. cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the POJO as a stateless EJB, there's nothing wrong with that approach.

From the wikipedia:  *EJB is a server-side model that encapsulates the business logic of an application.*

Your POJO class consumes a web service, so it performs a business logic for you.

EDIT >  Upon reading your comment, are you trying to access an EJB from outside of the Java EE container? Because if not, then you can inject your EJB into another EJB (they HAVE to be Stateless, both of them)

Comment: No they are both in the same project. In the same package in fact. It's just one is an EJB the other is a standard POJO for doing this separate twitter operation. I hadn't thought about also making this an EJB but the from where do I call it.  I'd have to remove the main class, yea?

Comment: I still don't understand, where that main method is. You could inject the EJBs either way. That really depends from where that method on your Twitter pojo gets called. You could put @Inject daoClass in the Twitter bean and call its method

Comment: Ah sorry, there is a main CLASS. It calls the Twitter class? If so, I would make the Twitter class EJB, inject it into the main class. And then either inject your DAO into Twitter or Main, depends on your software architecture. Anyway, you probably know, where I'm going with this.

Comment: I tried injecting the database access EJB into my string building class that contains the main method. the problem is that since all of my code in that class is in main it doesn't like referencing the EJB from a static context. I could try making the injection static I suppose

Comment: The problem is you can't reference an injected class from Main. It wants it to be a static class.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You cannot inject EJB into static field however, that's forbidden by the spec and makes total sense. Now the obvious question, how is it that you're in a static method? That seems a bit unusual to me. If you're in a web app, what are you using as an entry point to the main? I need to see your perspective correctly. Otherwise, the suggested approach of getting a handle by JNDI lookup would be the way to go.

Comment: Well I tried to separate out my code from the main method into their own classes and just use the main method to call and instantiate according to standard practice however I had some library functions that I could only address under Main and these created dependencies which cause almost all of my code to be done in main. including the call to the database EJB.  It was this call IOUtils.copy(twitterSource.openStream(), urlOutputStream); for some reason IOUtils did not allow instelf to be instantiated in another class. It had ot be main.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5726/discussion-between-randnum-and-tomas-plesek)

Comment: Post a code sample please, I have trouble uderstanding, what's going with that main method of yours. You don't instantiate the IOUtils, you just call a static method on the calss, it doesn't make any difference, where you call it from (be it static method or object method), or at least I don't see how it could be affected in this way. I would like to see the main method and know from where it's entered.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `InitialContext#lookup` method to obtain EJB reference from an application server.
For example:

```
@Stateless(name="myEJB")
public class MyEJB {

  public void ejbMethod() {
    // business logic
  }

}

public class TestEJB {

  public static void main() {
    MyEJB ejbRef = (MyEJB) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/myEJB");
    ejbRef.ejbMethod();
  }
}
```

However, note that the ejb name used for lookup may be vendor-specific. Also, EJB 3.1 introduces the idea of [portable JNDI names](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2009/12/portable-jndi-names-in-ejb-31.html) which should work for every application server.

Comment: Thank you, JNDI look up is one thing I haven't had to use yet. JEE6 with annotations makes things so much easier. What I did was just make a static instance of the EJB and call the method on that instance. It feels wrong to do this but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stand alone program that wishes to access an EJB you have a couple of options.

One is to simply use JNDI to look up the EJB. The EJB must have a Remote interface, and you need to configure the JNDI part for you container, as well as include any specific container jars within your stand alone application.

Another technique is to use the Java EE artifact know as the "application client". Here, there is a container provider wrapper for your class, but it provides a run time environment very similar to running the class within the container, notably you get things like EJB injection.

You app still runs in a separate JVM, so you still need to reference Remote EJBs, but the app client container handles a bunch of the boiler plate in getting your app connected to the server. This, too, while a Java EE artifact, is also container dependent in how to configure and launch an app client application.

Finally, there is basically little difference in how a POJO interact with the EJB container this way in contrast to a POJO deployed within the container. The interface is still a matter of getting the EJB injected (more easily done in Java EE 6 than before) or looking up a reference via JNDI. The only significant difference being that a POJO deployed in the container can use a Local interface instead of the Remote.

Comment: they're actually in the same web project I was just wondering if I should make it another EJB, leave it as a regular pojo, instantiate the other EJB and reference it from the other class. Or how I could get them to reference eachother.

Comment: If you don't need the transactional capabilities, or the other EJB lifecycle/interceptor capabilities, then just make it a POJO and move on. It's not that EJBs are particularly expensive, or any of that, but when "new TweetPojo()" does the job, just go with that.

Comment: yea I just need to get it into the database and to do that I have ot go through an EJB which contains the methods for database access. Other classes and servlets use this EJB so I don't think I can just convert it into a POJO.

Comment: It can be a simple pojo that calls the EJB like anything else. If it's in the web app, just look up the original EJB via JNDI and call those methods.